# Jenkins Job DSL: ConcurrentModificationException when too many jobs and the jobs finishing too fast

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a Jenkins pressure test to determine how many executors can be handled on my node:

```
// Jenkinsfile

int MAX_JOBS

static String jobTemplate(String name, int i) {    
    return """
job('$name') {
  steps {
    shell "/bin/bash /script/for/pressure/tests"
  }
}
"""
}

def parallelledStages(int maxJobs) {
    def stagesMap = [:]

    for (int i = 0; i < maxJobs; i ++) {
        def name = "test$i"

        def stageStep = {
            jobDsl scriptText: jobTemplate(name, i), sandbox: true
            build name
        }

        stagesMap[name] = stageStep
    }

    return stagesMap
}

pipeline {
    agent {
        label "pressure_test"
    }
    stages {
        stage("Init variables") {
            steps {
                script {
                    MAX_JOBS = 100
                }
            }
        }
        stage("Create and start jobs") {
            steps {
                script {
                    parallel parallelledStages(MAX_JOBS)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But in fact, when the pressure script finishs too fast (less than 30 seconds I think), some child jobs cannot start at all, and throws the following error:

```
Processing provided DSL script

java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextNode(LinkedHashMap.java:719)

    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedKeyIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:742)

    at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:343)

    at java.util.TreeSet.addAll(TreeSet.java:312)

    at java.util.TreeSet.<init>(TreeSet.java:160)

    at javaposse.jobdsl.plugin.actions.GeneratedObjectsRunAction.getModifiedObjects(GeneratedObjectsRunAction.java:47)

    at javaposse.jobdsl.plugin.ExecuteDslScripts.perform(ExecuteDslScripts.java:364)

    at jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildStep.perform(SimpleBuildStep.java:112)

    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor462.invoke(Unknown Source)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:92)

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:70)

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)

    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)

    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

And the seed job will throw the error finally:

```
hudson.AbortException
    at javaposse.jobdsl.plugin.ExecuteDslScripts.perform(ExecuteDslScripts.java:374)
    at jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildStep.perform(SimpleBuildStep.java:112)
Also:   hudson.AbortException
        at javaposse.jobdsl.plugin.ExecuteDslScripts.perform(ExecuteDslScripts.java:374)
        at jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildStep.perform(SimpleBuildStep.java:112)
    Caused: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Also:   hudson.AbortException
        at javaposse.jobdsl.plugin.ExecuteDslScripts.perform(ExecuteDslScripts.java:374)
        at jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildStep.perform(SimpleBuildStep.java:112)
    Caused: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Also:   hudson.AbortException
        at javaposse.jobdsl.plugin.ExecuteDslScripts.perform(ExecuteDslScripts.java:374)
        at jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildStep.perform(SimpleBuildStep.java:112)
    Caused: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor462.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:92)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:70)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

So just wondering:

1. Is there something wrong in the `parallel` operator? Maybe some HashMap should be locked?
2. How can I deal with this issue?